# Merging multiple arrays inside a array of objects into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a object where data is an array of objects, inside data object I have one users property which is an array.

I need to get all the users into a single array. I have written using `map` and `concat`.

Is there any way I can have a better solution, or this is correct?

See the below snippet.

```js
var response = {data: [{users: [1,2,3]}, {users: [4,5,6]}]}

var users = response.data.map(o => o.users)

const usersCollection = [].concat(...users)

console.log(usersCollection)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

> The `flat()` method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified ***depth***.

**`depth | Optional`**

> The depth level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.

```js
var response = {data: [{users: [1,2,3]}, {users: [4,5,6]}]}

var users = response.data.map(o => o.users).flat();

console.log(users);
```

You can also try with [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which is ***identical to a `map` followed by a call to `flat` of depth 1***.

```
var users = response.data.flatMap(o => o.users);
```

Comment: is this flat method is supported in nodejs version more than 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

If Using ES6, utilizing the power of `spread` with `Array.reduce`

```js
var response = {
  data: [{
    users: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    users: [4, 5, 6]
  }]
}

var users = response.data.reduce((accumulator, obj) => [...accumulator, ...obj.users], []);

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **ES6 Spread operator** you can do the job quick.

```
var response = {data: [{users: [1,2,3]}, {users: [4,5,6]}]}

let wantedArray = [];
for(let v of response.data){
  wantedArray.push(...v.users);
}

console.clear();
console.log(wantedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method first maps each element using a mapping function,
>   then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a map
>   followed by a flat of depth 1, but flatMap is often quite useful, as
>   merging both into one method is slightly more efficient

`response.data.flatMap(({users})=>users)`

You should be careful with vendor support though if you’re running in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
var response = {data: [{users: [1,2,3]}, {users: [4,5,6]}]}    
var NEWARRAY = [];
for(var v of response.data){
  NEWARRAY.push(...v.users);
}
console.log(NEWARRAY);
```

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate answers. This exact solution has already been provided.

Comment: FYI - The vast majority of authoritative bodies in the JS community recommend naming conventions where uppercase variables are used specifically for defining [constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming))... [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-constant-names), [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Examples), [Airbnb](http://airbnb.io/javascript/#naming--uppercase), [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp).